# Selecting value from database using where condition like below

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<select name="sample" class="form-control" id='select'>
  <?php 
    $sam1="attingal"; $sam2="kollam"; 
    $getstd="SELECT stdid,firstname,lastname FROM student WHERE centre='$sam1' AND centre='$sam2' ORDER BY firstname ASC"; 
    $qs=$conn->query($getstd); 
    $qs->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM); 
    while($getstd=$qs->fetch()) { 
  ?>
    <option value='<?php echo $getstd[0]; ?>'>
      <?php echo $getstd[1]." ".$getstd[2]; ?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Nothing is displaying when I run the above code

Comment: So, you have a field, and you want it to be both `attingal` AND `kollam`? Do you not see the issue here? Try using `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
WHERE centre='$sam1' AND centre='$sam2'
```

That condition can never be true. a field can't hold 2 different values at once.
You supposedly wanted OR, so change it to

```
WHERE centre='$sam1' OR centre='$sam2'
```